# How do I create a new pandas dataframe column with the contents of another, but only if the other column meets a condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boolean-logic

I have this line of code:

```
df['new_column']=df['price'][df['bathrooms']>=2 and df['bathrooms']<3]
```

Basically, I want to create a new column with the price of a listing (from column price), but only if the bathrooms column contains a value greater than or equal to 2, but less than three. I'm getting the error

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How do I correct this code?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 0):

You need proper parathensis, [you cannot use 'and' use ampsand (&) instead](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and use `loc` instead, try:

```
df['new_column']=df.loc[(df['bathrooms']>=2) & (df['bathrooms']<3), 'price']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this: [query in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
df1 =df.query('bathrooms>=2 and bathrooms<3')
df1[['price']]
```